# java Prepared Statement fails on null error

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I've got a problem I can't figure out, i'm sure it's easy but my google searches and Stackoverflow searches didn't get me there. The java documentation wasn't helping neither.
I've found a lot of problems where people make syntaxing errors in the SQL statement or in the code. I think mine is in the code.
It's about getting some information from the database by a query where the user can fill in it's own search information (a number).

Here is the code:
(I've tried multiple things so it might be that my code isn't the best anymore. Also I am new to java so keep that in consideration.)

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dbConnection;

import data.Mail;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import view.SelectionScreenCRA;

/**
 *
 * @author vm
 */
public class dbConnect {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Jeroen Veldhuijzen\\locaties.mdb;";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(dbConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("\nError: " + ex.toString() + ex.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static ArrayList<dbConnect> executeQuery(int cra) {


         ArrayList<dbConnect> locatie = new ArrayList<dbConnect>();

        Mail mail = new Mail();
        try{
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT Locatiegegevens.[Locatiegegevens], "
                + "Locatiegegevens.[ISP - Straatnaam], "
                + "Locatiegegevens.[ISP - Huisnummer],"
                + " Locatiegegevens.[ISP - Postcode], "
                + "Locatiegegevens.[ISP - Plaatsnaam], "
                + "Locatiegegevens.[G4S - Transportcode] "
                + "FROM Locatiegegevens "
                + "WHERE Locatiegegevens.[Locatiegegevens] = '?';");


        pst.setInt(1, cra);
        pst.execute();

        pst.close();
        conn.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERRROOOOR");

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
            Logger.getLogger(dbConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

        }
        return locatie;

    }

}
```

The int cra will be set here:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    dbConnect dbc = new dbConnect();
    dbConnect.executeQuery(Integer.parseInt(getCRA().getText()));        
}
```

The cra will be retrieved as a String and then parsed into an int when it will be passed to the executeQuery command.
If I sout the cra int, it will give me the int 9501 which is filled in in the textbox.
But if I run the query by pushing the button jButton1, there will be a null error:

```
null

class java.lang.NullPointerException
aug 09, 2012 12:43:04 PM dbConnection.dbConnect executeQuery
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.clearParameter(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:1022)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setInt(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:526)
    at dbConnection.dbConnect.executeQuery(dbConnect.java:62)
    at view.SelectionScreenCRA.jButton1ActionPerformed(SelectionScreenCRA.java:502)
    at view.SelectionScreenCRA.access$900(SelectionScreenCRA.java:29)
    at view.SelectionScreenCRA$11.actionPerformed(SelectionScreenCRA.java:333)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Is there someone who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: what value : getCRA().getText() ? Have you debug at what line are you getting null ERROR

Comment: In MS Access, a number should not be quoted: `[Locatiegegevens] = '?';");` should be `[Locatiegegevens] = ?;");`, I reckon.

Comment: Yes! You've got it Remou. I could swear I've tried it without the quotes, maybe there was something else wrong at that time (I've tried a gazillion things.

Comment: @VeldMuijz - he's got the fix, but his explanation is wrong.  1) This is not MS specific.  2) This is not to do with numbers.  The real explanation is that parameters place-holders should not be quoted ... because if you quote them you are *actually* writing an SQL string containing a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes which are around parameter marker (?). Also semicolon in the end of query string is not needed:

```
"WHERE Locatiegegevens.[Locatiegegevens] = ?");
```

Comment: Remou said the same.
Thx guys. Now I have to find out how I return all the columns of the row.

Comment: He said "a number should not be quoted". In general parameter markers should not be quoted (type doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Micko has identified the problem.  As he says, you should *never* put quotes around a parameter place-holder (?) in a query string.  It doesn't matter what the type is.

This is just to explain what is actually happening ... and why you get an NPE.

If you put quotes around the parameter marker, you are actually writing an SQL string.  When the `createPreparedStatment` analyses your query string, it doesn't find any markers at all.  That's OK<sup>1</sup> from a syntactic perspective ... but it means that the query does not mean what you intended it to mean.

Then it gets a bit murky.  The NPE occurs while you are trying to `set` the (non-existent) parameter 1.  But if you look at the stacktrace, it is actually in a method called `clearParameter`.  I haven't looked for the source-code of the MS JDBC drivers, but my **guess** is that the prepared statement parser creates an array of place-holder parameters.  But if it doesn't find any, it doesn't bother to allocate the array.  That's normally harmless ... but if you then attempt to set the value of a place-holder, it appears that the code is not checking properly, and generating an NPE by accident.

Either way, throwing an NPE in this situation is poor behaviour on the JDBC driver's part.  I'd call it a Bug!

**UPDATE**

I found the source code [here](http://pag-www.gtisc.gatech.edu/chord//examples/jdk/sun/jdbc/odbc/JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java.html) and my hypothesis was basically correct ... **except** that this is old Sun code, not Microsoft code.  (That *should have been* obvious from the package names ... duh!)

The problem is that `boundParams` is `null`.  If you look at line 2727, it is only initialized if the number of placeholders is greater than zero.  Bug!

---

<sup>1 - Actually, it is not OK because in this case you will most likely get an SQL error because the "string" doesn't match the type of the column.  But that analysis is performed when the query gets to the database server ... and for a lot of JDBC drivers this doesn't happen until you actually execute the query the first time.</sup>